# Default value for parameter of class where value is another class

Tags: c++, class

Title may be a little bit confusing but basically I have a class 'Quaternion' which has 2 parameters, the first being another instance of a class Vector3 and the other being a float.

Vector3 takes 3 floats as parameters and assigns them to x, y, and z.

I want to set default parameters for the Quaternion class but I am unsure how to set default parameters with a class as a parameter.

**Vector3**

```
class Vector3 {
  public:
    float x, y, z;

    Vector3(float uX, float uY, float uZ) {
      this->x = uX;
      this->y = uY;
      this->z = uZ; 
    }
};
```

**Quaternion**

```
class Quaternion {
  public:
    Vector3 axis;
    float scalar;

    Quaternion(Vector3 uAxis, float uScalar = 0) {
      axis = uAxis;
      scalar = uScalar;
    };
};
```

I would like to have the default parameter for `uAxis` to be a `Vector3` with x, y, and z set to `1, 0, 0` respectively, but i am unsure how i can do this.

Comment: I like the pattern of adding static defaults to the vector class itself. Maybe `up`, `right` and `forward`. You could then use `Vector3 uAxis = Vector3::right` or whatever x is in your environment. But I believe `Vector3 uAxis = Vector3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f)` would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you were looking for:

```
class Quaternion {
  public:
    Vector3 axis;
    float scalar;

    Quaternion(Vector3 uAxis = Vector3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), float uScalar = 0) {
      axis = uAxis;
      scalar = uScalar;
    };
};
```

It is possible to call a constructor of a class to set a default parameter. Here is the corresponding cpp reference [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments).

Comment: wow after seeing the solution it seems so obvious lol, ty man.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want. Always use the initialisation list on the constructor unless you have to do something with the parameters [docs](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c49-prefer-initialization-to-assignment-in-constructors). Also I am passing the `uAxis` as const reference which is always a good thing to do for ADT (Abstract Data Types) Unless you have special requirements.

```
 class Quaternion 
 {
    Vector3 axis;
    float scalar;

 public:
    Quaternion(const Vector3 & uAxis = Vector3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), float uScalar = 0) :
      axis(uAxis),
      scalar(uScalar)
    {
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [default member initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) for `axis` within `Quaternion`. That way, just creating a `Quaternion q{}` would set `axis` to whatever you want. [[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/7PM5sah55)

```cpp
class Quaternion {
public:
    Vector3 axis{1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    float scalar{};

    Quaternion() = default;
    ...
};
```

For the `Quaternion(Vector3 uAxis, float uScalar)` constructor, it would be preferable to use a member initializer list:

```cpp
Quaternion(Vector3 uAxis, float uScalar) : axis{uAxis}, scalar{uScalar} {};
```

Also, you can remove `Vector3`'s constructor, making  `Vector3` an [aggregate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```cpp
struct Vector3 {
    float x{};
    float y{};
    float z{};
};

Vector3 v{1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
```